# Exporting data from Mysql into Sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

i want to export from mysql into sqlite. currently i can export from mysql into a dump file. the only problem is importing to a sqlite db. the import feature on sqlite does not currently support the dump from mysql. is there any other way.

Comment: It looks like there are some possible solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164033/export-a-mysql-database-to-sqlite-database

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, it's a very cool AWK script, which just needs the MySQL dump. Find it here - https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite